# jQuery accordion with MVC 4 Razor | keep the active pane open

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I am using jQuery Accordion. Within accordion I have few links which makes a call to controller actions.

```
    <div id="accordion" class="accordion">
    <h1 class="requestsheader"><a href="#1">Header 1</a></h1>
    <div>
        <table>
@foreach (var item in Model)
            {
<tr>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <div class="requestButton">
                            @Html.ActionLink("Send Request for Authorization", "SendRequest", new { id = item.Id })
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
}
</table>
    </div>

<h1 class="requestsheader"><a href="#2">header 2</a></h1>
    <div>
...
...
</div>

</div>
```

following is javascript code:

```
$("#accordion").accordion({
        collapsible: true, clearStyle: true, heightStyle: "content", navigation: true,active:false   
    })
```

All the panes collapse after I make call to an action. I need a way to keep current pane opened after an action is called. If this can be done using hidden fields, What is the proper way of using hiddenfields in mvc.

Comment: It doesn't make seance to open `accordion` in `httppost`. Can you elaborate more why you want to open the `accordion` in post.

Comment: not just post, suppose I have grid with paging inside my accordion, pane collapses while moving from page to another.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think using cookie is the best way. Following is how I resolved it. Hope this will help someone looking for similar solution.

Following code goes to document.ready function:

```
  var activeIndex = parseInt(getCookie('openedPane'));

$("#accordion").accordion({
    collapsible: true, clearStyle: true, heightStyle: "content", navigation: true, active: activeIndex,
    activate: function (event, ui) {
        var index = $(this).children('h1').index(ui.newHeader);            
        setCookie('openedPane', index, 1);            
    },
    create: function (event, ui) {            
        deleteCookie('openedPane');   //Deleting the cookie when accordion is created         
    }
});
```

Following is the code to set/get/delete cookie in Javascript:

```
function setCookie(name, value, days) {    
if (days) {
    var date = new Date();
    date.setTime(date.getTime() + (days * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
    var expires = "; expires=" + date.toGMTString();
}
else var expires = "";
document.cookie = name + "=" + value + expires + "; path=/";
}

function getCookie(name) {
    var nameEQ = name + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for (var i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') c = c.substring(1, c.length);
        if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0) return c.substring(nameEQ.length, c.length);
    }
    return null;
}

function deleteCookie(name) {
    setCookie(name, "", -1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could post a hidden variable containing the panel that you want to be active when the post returns, add that to the viewbag, and then conditionally activate that panel.

You'd have to show the form you're using for me to comment on how to post that additional variable, (don't know if its ajax, form, actionlink, etc), but here's what the rest would look like:

```
public ActionResult MyPagingMethod(int page = 1, int? panel = null) // or whatever your action is
{
    // do work

    ViewBag.PanelToOpen = panel;

    // return view
}
```

then javascript

```
$("#accordion").accordion({
    collapsible: true, clearStyle: true, heightStyle: "content", navigation: true,active:false   
})
@if(Viewbag.PanelToOpen != null) {
    $('#accordion').accordion('activate', @ViewBag.PanelToOpen);
}
```

Alternatively, (and probably favorably) you could use javascript to set a cookie for the accordion panel that's open, and on page load, if the cookie is set, activate that panel. This separates the client logic of the panel being open from the server.

Answer (score 0):

thank you very much 
finally my code is this. it works with active accordion pane.

```
 $(function () {
      $("#accordion").accordion({
           collapsible: true
           clearStyle: true,
           heightStyle: "content",
           navigation: true, 
           active: false 
       });    
 });
```